# Zend_Form unable to set custom element validation message if Zend_Translate is set

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, translation

It is absolutely impossible to set custom element validation message if `Zend_Translator` is applied to `Zend_Form`. 
Please see my example...

```
class App_Form extends Zend_Form 
{

    public function init() 
    {

        parent::init();

        //let's create and set translator for our form
        $translations = array(
            Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Value is required for this field.' //just one line of translations as example
        );
        $adapter = new Zend_Translator('array', $translations);
        $this->setTranslator($adapter);

        //now we're going to add some text element
        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('firstname');
        $element
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setFilters(array('StringTrim'))
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
        ;

        //now we're overriding error message for key with name Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY
        $element->getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Please enter your first name.', Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY);
        $this->addElement($element);

        if (!$this->isValid(array('firstname' => ''))) {
            print_r($this->getErrorMessages());
            //we'll still get "Value is required for this field." message
            //if we will try to disable translator we'll get correct message "Value is required for this field."
        }

    }

}
```

This error occures when `Zend_Form::getErrorMessages()` method is called.
This method overrides current message templates with translated message templates.

So, it seems impossible complete this task without modifying `Zend_Validate_Abstract`

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a step debugger. Take a look why the set value is either not set or not used. That might already answer your question. IIRC, when you do some tailoring with Zend Form you need to reverse engineer it in case something does not work as expected as it is pretty complex.

Comment: @hakre, I'm alredy using `xdebug` and I see that `Zend_Form::getErrorMessages()` overrides all custom messages when appying translation to form. And it seems to me that it is imppossible to complete this task without modifying parent (`Zend_Validate_Abstract`) of all validation classes `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty`. :(

Comment: Maybe if you change a bit of the ordering? And can't you assign a custom error message within the form definition?

Comment: @hakre, sure I can solve this problem modifying Zend lib. I've made a bug report: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12355

Comment: Faced this problem today. Still no solution or bug resolve?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know. Not using ZF anymore.